# Difference between Oracle XE v SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-xe

I am confused between Oracle XE and SQL Developer? What is the main difference between the two? I am assuming that Oracle XE is the database while SQL Developer is like an IDE to perform queries ?

Answer (score 10):

Oracle XE is a database server.  SQL Developer is a client.  The client (SQL Developer) connects to the database (Oracle XE) in order to allow you to submit queries for the database to run and to format the results that the database returns.

Many different client applications can connect to your database.  And SQL Developer can connect to many different databases (not just Oracle databases).

Comment: Thanks Justin. Makes Sense now.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle SQL Developer is the Oracle Database IDE. A free graphical user interface.

Oracle XE is the Express Edition (Free) of the Oracle DB.