# I am learning SQL. Should I download Oracle Developer edition or Express edition?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am learning SQL but a bit confused about to download Orcale SQL Developer or the Express edition. Thank you in advance for your input.

Comment: No. Download neither.

Comment: SQL Developer is a GUI not a database. You probably need both. https://stackoverflow.com/q/25797518 But if you're just interested in learning SQL then it's probably easier to get started with something simpler than Oracle.

Comment: Due to its close (closer than most other DBMS) adherence to the SQL standard, [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) is a really good DBMS to start learning SQL

Comment: Another good place to learn SQL without needing to install anything is http://livesql.oracle.com

Answer (score 3):

SQL Developer is a GUI for working with Oracle Database. It's free, and will make learning SQL via Oracle much easier.

Oracle Database Express Edition (XE) is a free version of the database.

Another option is our [VirtualBox appliance](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html). It's a Linux vm you can run on any machine and has a database, sample data, and hands on labs to help you learn the tech.

[image]

I talk about that vm in detail [here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/02/introducing-the-otn-developer-day-database-12c-virtualbox-image/)

Answer (score 0):

Download oracle 11g express edition

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).